# Отключается соединение с интернетом при закрытии крышки ноутбука

Tags: windows, windows-10

Заметила проблему, только после обновления на Win10. У меня подключен ноут к телевизору, при этом крышка закрыта, wi-fi адаптер настроен, всё работает, при первой передаче пакетов wi-fi продолжает работать, но интернет пропадает. Шлюз - маршрутизатор, настроен через PPPoE, всё раньше работало отлично. Есть предположение, что меняются какие-то настройки при смене режимов которых раньше не было. В самом адаптере изменений нет, с питанием естественно всё тоже настроено, куда смотреть? Очень нужно для работы, помогите.

Comment: Не закрывайте крышку!

Comment: А ноутбук в sleep точно не уходит при закрытии крышки?.. Какое действие стоит у вас на закрытие крышки?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Comment: вопрос есть в тех поддержке, я отправляла, только там по сути ответ про питание. В слип точно не уходит я же написала, в вопросе. Просто  это частая проблема судя по посту на оф сайте, а решения нигде нет. Если никак, то меня бы этот ответ устроил, а пока вернулась на 7 и всё сразу заработало, только это проблему не решает для win10.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках адаптера необходимо отключить функцию энергосбережения. После сна - он не хочет стартовать Wi-Fi

[image]